# "Spelling checker" or "spell checker"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, orthography, formality, writing

I've always thought a *spelling checker* is a tool that checks spelling.  I know a growing number of people say *spell checker*, but I've always considered that slang.  Recently I did a search for the term and saw that many professionally-edited outlets use the shorter version. Has the shorter term become acceptable in formal writing?

Does it generalize to the verb form as well?

1. I need to spell check my document.
2. I need to check the spelling in my document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spellcheck](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1293013) and [spellchecker](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1293014) are both in *Oxford Living Dictionaries*, on line.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually seen it used in combination form: [spellchecker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spellchecker). The verb is *spellcheck* and it conjugates the same way *check* does. It's also used as *[spell checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_checker)*, and I guess you can take your pick.

Comment: I always use *spelling checker*; a *spell checker* is something Harry Potter needs.

Comment: @Martha: But I bet J. K. Rowling used a spellchecker! :)

Answer (score 1):

On the copy of the NOAD installed on the Mac computer I am using to answer, for *spelling checker* I only read *another term for spellchecker*. *Spell checker* is reported as possible variant of *spell-checker*.

*To spell-check* (or *to spell check*) means to check the spelling of a text using a spell-checker; the meaning of *spell-checker* is reported to be *a computer program that checks the spelling of words in files of text, typically by comparison with a stored list of words*.

*To check the spelling* would have a more generic meaning that *to spell check*, as the latter verb implicates the use of a computer program. It is possible that, as nowadays the computer is used also as text editor, *to spell check* is used even when the operation has not be done with a computer (e.g., *the professor has spell-checked my essay*).

Searching for *[check] the spelling* and *[spellcheck]* on the *Corpus of Contemporary American* (*[check]* matches *check*, *checks*, *checked*) I get the following data (the values are the frequencies per million; the images can also be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJhmL.png), and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah59U.png)):

[image: usage by context]
[image: usage per year]

The data evidences that *spellcheck* is used more frequently in the last 10 years.

Comment: The image isn't showing up...

Comment: That's strange: I see it. Probably it depends from its size; I will try with a smaller image.

Comment: I see the images now.

Comment: Can you please emend and explain in detail 'On the NOAD reports spelling checker, but it simply describes it as another term for spell-checker'? This seems to be the substance of the answer. I'm not sure where the other research really comes in; relative frequencies of appearances of 'spellchecker' (3 forms?) and 'spelling checker' are surely appropriate? I'm fairly sure that they're interchangeable (no / negligible human / literary false-positives) to a very large degree.

Answer (score 0):

*Spell check* is a little more informal and more modern-ish of a word as a verb, but it is grammatically correct. Usually it refers to Microsoft Office Word or OpenOffice.
*Checking the spelling* is the more uncommon of the two, but still correctly used. (Some people just use spell check instead of checking the spelling because they think it's a waste or precious breath.)

Comment: I edited your answer to make clear that (as I suppose) when you said that "spell check" was a more informal word, you meant (as the question seemed to be asking) in its use as a verb. If that's not correct, please do edit it back.

Comment: As long it isn't edited so much that it strays from its only main point, I'm fine with moderators editing my answers.

Answer (score -2):

It's not all that difficult , even though our English language is a contradiction of itself .  You can call it as a verb , to spell check or spellcheck if one wishes , HOWEVER , based on our building of our language , to spell check is the action verb eg , "Please spell check that document" or "Spellcheck that document."
As a NOUN , there's ONLY one way to spell it ---- it's a spell-check(er) eg , "They performed a spell-check or we need a spell-checker to do its work. "   There . Peace.

Comment: Please consider including a reference. (See [*How to reference material written by others*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).)